# Ad hoc simulation in ns2 using antnet algorithm

Tags: c++, networking, ns2

Please provide me the code for ad hoc network simulation with antnet and ns2. I have successfully Installed ns2 and antnet.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Anthocnet**

---

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/ns-users/anthocnet|sort:date

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/tags/anthocnet/

---

'anthocnet_ns234.patch.gz' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNTTNVU1p4N1Exbnc/view?usp=sharing

'anthocnet_ns235.patch' https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNOXN1T1V2a1pPYjg/view?usp=sharing

[ns2](/questions/tagged/ns2)

Comment: There is no source code or anything to just apply to ns2.